# htaccess redirect directories with subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Have ran into an issue when adding WordPress multisite and then subsequently moving some old posts from the main site to a new subdomain. Those moved posts (their text) carry over fine (using one of several methods available) the problem comes when the front page of the new subdomain looks for featured images it is trying to load

subdomain.example.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/{blog-id}/{dated_subdirectories}

Is there a way to - perhaps using htaccess - forward/redirect those requests to:

example.com/wp-content/uploads/{dated_subdirectories}

I have tried various ways including [.htaccess redirect for images from old folder to new folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366078/htaccess-redirect-for-images-from-old-folder-to-new-folder) and I either get a 500 error or the WordPress nothing found page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule in `wp-content/uploads/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp-content/uploads/

RewriteRule ^sites/[^/]+/(.+)$ $1 [L,R=302,NC]
```

Comment: When I add that htaccess it loads the Apache 'Index of/' page

Comment: Do you have .htaccess in `wp-content` directory?

Comment: No. Only htaccess is in the root of example.com and contain standard WordPress sudomain multisite and WP Better Security rules

Comment: Thanks for this, it works. I now have a separate htaccess issue but I will have to investigate and see if it's related.